# Hard disk keeps running (Windows 7)

Tags: hard-drive, process-explorer, svchost

[image]Windows 7 64-bit.
I hear HDD running constantly and HDD LED blinking.
I quit all applications, even deleted antivirus software (BitDefender)
but it is still running.

I searched many helps, watched 'Process Monitor'  and it seems that
STacSV64.exe and svchost.exe are doing something.

in 'Services', I stopped bluetooth, gps something, 
also stopped 'superftech' and 'windowssearch'.

What would be the problem?
CPU usage is currently less than 1%.

My system is dell laptop cpu i5 ivy-bridge (3rd gen), ram 6gb, HDD 500GB + 32GB SSD (it's ultra book). I bought it this September.

RE : I added capture of resource monitor.
MsMpEng.exe seems to be Microsoft Security Essential I just installed,
but I stopped scanning. But real time protection is still on.
I still hear this hard disc spinning...

Comment: You need to widen the file column so that the entire file name can be seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should loop in the built-in Resources Monitor (Task Manager > Performance tab > Resource Monitor), you can see under Disk Activity which process access files and how much.

[image: Resource Monitor]